# ADO.Net Entity Framework Generate Database From Model (Wrong Database Showing)

Tags: database, entity-framework, ado.net, model

I am using the ADO.net Entity Framework and when i right click in my model designer and select 'Generate Database From Model' I see the script pop up, but with the wrong database name. How can I change which database my Model should interact with? I feel my solution may be talking to the wrong database!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the connectionstring in web.config or app.config. That is what EF uses the connect to the DB.

Comment: Yep, it was the correct method :) The DB string here was wrong, I wasn't sure where the EF grabbed it from, thanks!