# Update model from database: Visual Studio uses the wrong database

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I have a project with multiple EF databases; each EF model is in its own project, referenced from the other parts of the database.

Occasionally when I use the `Update Model from Database...` feature (right-clicking the graphical .EDMX view), Visual Studio gets into a state where it tries to update the .EDMX file for model A from the database associated with model B.  For example, it shows "new tables" in the DB that it wants to import (which are actually in the other DB).  Even exiting/restarting Visual Studio doesn't resolve the problem.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488557/ado-net-entity-framework-generate-database-from-model-wrong-database-showing) seemed to express the problem I'm seeing, but the accepted answer doesn't address my issue.

What is Visual Studio using to configure how it connects to the DB to find updates?  Things I have checked:

- My app.config connectionString in the DB project points to the right place.  This is the file I would expect it to use.
- I have tried setting the "Current Startup Project" to a an application that doesn't reference the "incorrect" DB project, thinking perhaps other projects' app/web.config connectionStrings might interfere; no visible effect.
- Server Explorer shows a data connection to the "correct" DB, but not the "incorrect" one.  This is probably a red herring; it showed as disconnected until I clicked on it, so I doubt it was being used anyway.
- There is no string matching the name of the "incorrect" project/DB in the .csproj file.  The .sln file contains only the expected project references.  There is no .csproj.user file.

Any ideas?  Is this a Visual Studio bug?

UPDATE:  Other things tried:

- Deleting the .suo file doesn't affect the problem.
- I found some unexpected .datasource files that Visual Studio added under Properties at some point; moving these elsewhere hasn't had an effect, and Visual Studio hasn't attempted to recreate them.  I looked inside, there's nothing referencing the other DB/project, just a GenericObjectDataSource element with items referencing the "correct" project.  The presence of this file makes me suspicious but I'm currently stumped for how to probe further.  I don't see equivalent files in any of the other projects in the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/facepalm

Disregard.  There were lingering tables in the "correct" database left over from the team's refactor of those tables out into the other database.  The phantom tables were actually there in the DB.